# No option found to change the language of the Python extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My visual studio is configured to be in english but the extension is getting installed in spanish. I would like to switch it to english also.

I have seen that there are many languages supported for the commands extension, but I can't seem to find an option in the extension settings. And could not find any relevant information about this appart from the mention of the support of the languages in the readme.

Thanks!

Comment: welcome! which extension? is it spanish only? i would contact the developer of the extension.

Comment: the extension is the Python extension, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python

Comment: Also the developer mentions: "If you have a question about how to accomplish something with the extension, please ask on Stack Overflow"

Comment: it seems like a bug more than anything.